# Changing default username/password in RockMongo

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I've just set up RockMongo as per [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo#Quick_Install), but I can't see how to change my username/password from the defaults (admin/admin).

In the config.php file there are two commented out lines to set mongo_user and mongo_pass, but  these are database specific (I believe), and I've tried changing them but the login credentials for RockMongo are still admin/admin.

Anyone know how to change them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the line in `config.php` just below where you were looking:

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["control_users"]["admin"] = "admin";
```

The first *admin* is the username and the second the password.
There is a comment on that line mentioning the caveat that this only works if *mongo_auth* is set to false (which is the default).

Comment: ah perfect thanks. would have been more obvious if the defaults were admin/password!

Answer (score 0):

Here is configuration guide: http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/configuration

There is a mongo_auth demo and control_auth demo.

Answer (score 0):

In the version 2014 Q4 there is a new bug, even if:

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = false;
```

You will still need to comment out:

```
// $MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_user"] = ...
// $MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_pass"] = ...
```

Which is a change in the config from the 2013 version I was running, which did not mind those two lines uncommented.

In total what worked for me when i upgraded is this:

```
// $MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_db"] = "MONGO_DATABASE";
// $MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_user"] = ...
// $MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_pass"] = ...
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = false;
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["control_auth"] = false;
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["control_users"]["admin-name"] = "admin-password";
```